# How can i make changes in the navbar so that it is responsive to mobile view as well

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have created a nav bar in a ejs file then using this file by including in all the files.
The problem is it is okay in desktop view but it is not responsive for mobile view as it is not using the entire screen and some space is left in the mobile screen.
Here is my nav bar file which i'm including in all of my files.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <!--   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
  target="#navbarColor01" 
  aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
  navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/users/home">Home <span class="sr-only"> 
   (current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/users/pldReports">M &amp; E</a>
          </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/expense/">Expense</a>
      </li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/procurement/">Asset Requisition</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/procurement/getvendorListView">Impaneled Vendor</a>
    </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">   
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-3" data-toggle="dropdown" 
   aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">Timesheets</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-info" aria- 
 labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-3">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/timesheets/taskListView">Tasks</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/timesheets/timesheetListView">Timesheets</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/timesheet">Calendar</a>
          </div>
      </li>
  
      <% if(objUser.isManager) { %> 
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-toggle="dropdown" 
         aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"> Manage Approvals</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-info" aria- 
        labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/approvals/pldFormApprovals">PLD Form Approval</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/approvals/expenseApprovals">Expense Approval</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Procurement Approval</a>
          </div>
      </li>
      <% } %>
      
      </ul>
      <form class="form my-2 my-lg-0">
      
          <ul class="my-2 my-sm-0 navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="float:right">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-user "></i>&nbsp; <%= objUser.name%> </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-info" aria- 
     labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/editProfile">Edit Profile</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/logout">Log out</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
      
      </form>
  
  </div>
  </nav>
```

it is showing in mobile view as:

[image]

i'm uising this file as <% include ./partials/navbar %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at Media Queries, as it'll help you style an element of a page depending on the screen size.

Take a look at the example below.

I have added some queries or each screen size, and I'm changing the background color of an element depending on what the visitor is using.

```css
/* background is blue on default */
.cool { background-color:blue; } 

 /* if visitor is visiting from a tablet (640px), make background-color orange*/
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .cool  { background-color:orange; }
}

/* if visitor is on their laptop, make the background yellow */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cool  { background-color:yellow; } 
}

/* Desktops  */
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .cool  { background-color:red; } 
}
```

I'm using `min-width` instead of `max-width`, because as soon as the screen size reaches the minimum width of X, the new CSS rule written inside that query, will take effect.

```html
<div class="cool">
   you are cool!
</div>
```

**Links:**

[Demo on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzc87wx5/)

[Read about @media on W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: I provided you with a demo, if you re-size the screen, you'll see the code taking effect. If you provide me with what your goal is other than "make it responsive", I can help you a bit more :D